# calculate sum of squares with rows above

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mean

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Value         Type       X_sq
-1.975767     Weather   
-0.540979     Fruits
-2.359127     Fruits
-2.815604     Corona
-0.929755     Weather
```

I want to iterate through each row and calculate a sum of squares value for each row above (only if the Type matches). I want to put this value in the X.sq column.

So for example, in the first row, there's nothing above. So only (-1.975767 x -1.975767). In the second row, there's no FRUITS row above it, so it will just be -0.540979 x -0.540979. However, in the third row, when we scan all previous rows, we should find that FRUITS is already there. So we should **get the last's FRUIT's  .....  X_sq** value and calculate a new sum of squares.

```
Value         Type       X_sq
-1.975767     Weather   -1.975767 * -1.975767    = x
-0.540979     Fruits    -0.540979 * -0.540979    = y
-2.359127     Fruits    y + ( -2.359127 x -2.359127)  
-2.815604     Corona    -2.815604 * -2.815604
-0.929755     Weather   x + (-0.929755 * -0.929755)
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

```
def updateSS(X_sq, X_new):
    return X_sq + X_new**2
```

EDIT:

```
----> 1 df['sumOfSquares'] = df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2).groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country']).cumsum()
     

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:1929, in Series.groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   1925 axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   1927 # error: Argument "squeeze" to "SeriesGroupBy" has incompatible type
   1928 # "Union[bool, NoDefault]"; expected "bool"
-> 1929 return SeriesGroupBy(
   1930     obj=self,
   1931     keys=by,
   1932     axis=axis,
   1933     level=level,
   1934     as_index=as_index,
   1935     sort=sort,
   1936     group_keys=group_keys,
   1937     squeeze=squeeze,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   1938     observed=observed,
   1939     dropna=dropna,
   1940 )

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:882, in GroupBy.__init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    879 if grouper is None:
    880     from pandas.core.groupby.grouper import get_grouper
--> 882     grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
    883         obj,
    884         keys,
    885         axis=axis,
    886         level=level,
    887         sort=sort,
    888         observed=observed,
    889         mutated=self.mutated,
    890         dropna=self.dropna,
    891     )
    893 self.obj = obj
    894 self.axis = obj._get_axis_number(axis)

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py:882, in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    880         in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    881     else:
--> 882         raise KeyError(gpr)
    883 elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    884     # Add key to exclusions
    885     exclusions.add(gpr.key)

KeyError: 'themes'
even though themes is there. Themes = type
```

Comment: What about the final "Weather" row? Will that include the sum from the first row?

Comment: yup @Mortz we should scan all the above and look for the last existing matching TYPE row

Comment: If there are 3 consecutive Fruits, what should we do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you populate the `X_sq` column with expected values for all the rows

Comment: The first row should have -0.540979 * -0.540979. The second row should have (-2.359127*-2.359127) + -0.540979 * -0.540979. Now let's say this value equals to z. Now the third row's value is y. So in the third row, X_sq will be z + x (from the  FRUIT line just above it) @Corralien

Comment: And for other rows? Should be blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['X_sq'] = df['Value'].pow(2).groupby(df['Type']).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
      Value     Type      X_sq
0 -1.975767  Weather  3.903655
1 -0.540979   Fruits  0.292658
2 -2.359127   Fruits  5.858138
3 -2.815604   Corona  7.927626
4 -0.929755  Weather  4.768100
```

Comment: No, OP needs to check not just shifted by 1 - but all rows.

Comment: So weather should be included?

Comment: here, I get 0.0 even in the first row, which is not how it should be@Corralien

Comment: @Corralien - Yeah that's what I think from OP's comment.

Comment: @x89. It's better with the result now :)

Comment: Nice. Thanks @mozway!

Comment: Is it possible to use this to group based on two cols instead of one, Type & Country? I tried this but got an error as described in the edited qs: ```df['sumOfSquares'] = df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2).groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country']).cumsum()```

Comment: Try: `df['sumOfSquares'] = df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2).groupby(df['themes', 'suppliers_country']).cumsum()` I added `df` before `['themes', ...]`

Comment: Maybe use: `df['sumOfSquares'] = df.assign(sumOfSquares=df['avg_country_tone'].pow(2)).groupby(['themes', 'suppliers_country'])['sumOfSquares'].cumsum()`

Answer (score 0):

You first build an id for consecutive rows with same type

```
groupid = (df['Type'] != df['Type'].shift()).cumsum()
```

You can then group the dataframe on it and again use `cumsum` on each group:

```
df['X_sq'] = df.groupby(groupid)['Value'].transform(lambda x: (x*x).cumsum())
```

You should get as expected:

```
      Value     Type      X_sq
0 -1.975767  Weather  3.903655
1 -0.540979   Fruits  0.292658
2 -2.359127   Fruits  5.858138
3 -2.815604   Corona  7.927626
4 -0.929755  Weather  0.864444
```

Comment: did you actually test it with the data? Because in my case, I get the squares correctly but they're not being added with the previous type row

Comment: @x89. Yes I did.. with the data I could copy from your post... But your original post only added values for Fruits because they were consecutive and did not add for Weather.