# calculate standard deviation by grouping two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Originally, I had a dataset that looked like this:

```
Value         Theme       
-1.975767     Weather     
-0.540979     Fruits      
-2.359127     Fruits      
-2.815604     Corona      
-0.929755     Weather     
-0.929755     Weather
```

I wanted to find std of values according to their themes. A general forumla for Standard deviation can be this:

```
def calculateSD(sumOfSquares, mean, n):
    nominator = sumOfSquares - ((mean*mean)*n)
    denominator = n-1
    variance = nominator/denominator
    std = variance**0.5
    return std
```

Here, n is the number of occurences of a theme so far. At first, I thought it might be a good idea to calculate the sumOfsquares and mean for each row.
This is how I calculated the values (and they are correct) - more details about the calculation here ([calculate sum of squares with rows above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71066800/calculate-sum-of-squares-with-rows-above/71067095?noredirect=1#comment125633505_71067095)):

```
df['sumOfSquares'] = df['value'].pow(2).groupby(df['theme']).cumsum()
df['mean'] = df.groupby('theme', as_index=False)['value'].expanding().mean().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)
df['n'] = df.groupby(['themes']).cumcount()+1    #number of occurences of a theme so far
df['std'] = calculateSD(df['sumOfSquares'], df['mean'], df['n'])
```

However, the method does not seem efficient. How can I directly calculate the standard deviation without doing these three steps separately? Are there any library functions?

Because now, I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Value         Theme       Country
-1.975767     Weather     China
-0.540979     Fruits      China
-2.359127     Fruits      China
-2.815604     Corona      Brazil
-0.929755     Weather     UK
-0.929755     Weather     UK
```

So instead of just theme, I also want a separation/grouping for Counry.

For example, I wanted to consider these three separately:

```
Value         Theme       Country   n
-1.975767     Weather     China     1
```

```
Value         Theme       Country   n
-0.540979     Fruits      China.    1
-2.359127     Fruits      China     2
```

```
Value         Theme       Country   n
-0.929755     Weather     UK        1
-0.929755     Weather     UK        2
```

What's the best way to calculate std in this case?

Comment: `pandas` is your good friend for doing grouped aggregation. Your goal can be achieved with `original_dataset.groupby(['Theme', 'Country'])['Value'].std()`. By default it has an argument `ddof=1` which is equivalent to your `n-1` term. 

Check out this page for more aggregation methods 

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html

Comment: I tried this ```df['std'] = df.groupby(['themes', 'country'])['value'].std()``` but I get this ```TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index```@RaymondKwok

Comment: I am confused. Does exactly this line of code give you the error, or another line of code give you it?

Comment: yup this line gives me an error @RaymondKwok

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['Theme', 'Country']).Value.std()
```

If you also want the `n`:

```
df.groupby(['Theme', 'Country']).agg(Value=('Value', 'std'),
                                     n=('Value', 'count')).reset_index()
```

Comment: I tried the first one but it gives me ```TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index```