# TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index when grouping 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, standard-deviation

I have a dataset that looks like this (+ some other cols):

```
Value         Theme       Country
-1.975767     Weather     China
-0.540979     Fruits      China
-2.359127     Fruits      China
-2.815604     Corona      Brazil
-0.929755     Weather     UK
-0.929755     Weather     UK
```

I want to find standard deviations for the values after grouping by Themes and Countries (as explained here [calculate standard deviation by grouping two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080234/calculate-standard-deviation-by-grouping-two-columns/71080528#71080528)

```
df = pd.read_csv('./Brazil.csv')
df['std'] = df.groupby(['themes', 'country'])['value'].std()
```

However, currently, I get this error:

```
File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3656, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   3653     self._setitem_array([key], value)
   3654 else:
   3655     # set column
-> 3656     self._set_item(key, value)

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3833, in DataFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3823 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   3824     """
   3825     Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
   3826 
   (...)
   3831     ensure homogeneity.
   3832     """
-> 3833     value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3835     if (
   3836         key in self.columns
   3837         and value.ndim == 1
   3838         and not is_extension_array_dtype(value)
   3839     ):
   3840         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
   3841         if not self.columns.is_unique or isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:4534, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   4532 # We should never get here with DataFrame value
   4533 if isinstance(value, Series):
-> 4534     return _reindex_for_setitem(value, self.index)
   4536 if is_list_like(value):
   4537     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)

File /usr/local/Cellar/ipython/8.0.1/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:10985, in _reindex_for_setitem(value, index)
  10981     if not value.index.is_unique:
  10982         # duplicate axis
  10983         raise err
> 10985     raise TypeError(
  10986         "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"
  10987     ) from err
  10988 return reindexed_value

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Comment: You can't directly insert the result of a groupby aggregation in the input dataframe. Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: I want to save the value of std in a new col ```df['std']```@mozway

Comment: Can you provide the explicit expected output as text in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `rolling` method to calculate cumulative standard deviations for each group.

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
import io
text_csv = '''Value,Theme,Country
-1.975767,Weather,China
-0.540979,Fruits,China
-2.359127,Fruits,China
-2.815604,Corona,Brazil
-0.929755,Weather,UK
-0.929755,Weather,UK'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_csv))

# Calculate cumulative standard deviations
df_std = df.groupby(['Theme', 'Country'], as_index=False)['Value'].rolling(len(df), min_periods=1).std()

# Merge the original df with the cumulative std values
df_std = df.join(df_std.drop(['Theme', 'Country'], axis=1).rename(columns={'Value': 'CorrectedStd'}))
```

### Output

|  | Value | Theme | Country | CorrectedStd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -1.97577 | Weather | China | nan |
| 1 | -0.540979 | Fruits | China | nan |
| 2 | -2.35913 | Fruits | China | 1.28562 |
| 3 | -2.8156 | Corona | Brazil | nan |
| 4 | -0.929755 | Weather | UK | nan |
| 5 | -0.929755 | Weather | UK | 0 |

Comment: I don't think this is correct because the standard deviation values should not be the same for Fruits/china. I also tested with another dataset and it shows the same corrected STD for all rows of the same theme/country. there should be a re-calculation every time

Comment: There is only one standard deviation value defined for a population. Therefore, it is not possible by definition to have different STD values among multiple Fruits/China rows. Perhaps it is not the standard deviation, but the Z-score that you want. See the definition of Z-score: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Comment: When I calculate the standard deviation for a row, I want to imagine that there are no rows below it. I only want to consider the rows above it. So for example, when a new row comes in, I calculate a new std value, which will of course be different than the previous one since the overall mean/sum of squares values (which are used in calculating the std) would also be changed. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: A great explanation. I completely understand it now. What you want to get is cumulative standard deviations. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Great, could you please also explain how the first code line (rolling(Len(df)) works as well

Comment: @x89 - it is `expanding` alternative, it rolling per groups. Here is length of groups less like length of df, so working well `rolling(len(df)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) with remove first level for new column by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) should be simplier solution:

```
df['std']  = (df.groupby(['Theme', 'Country'])['Value']
                .expanding()
                .std()
                .droplevel([0,1]))
print (df)
      Value    Theme Country       std
0 -1.975767  Weather   China       NaN
1 -0.540979   Fruits   China       NaN
2 -2.359127   Fruits   China  1.285625
3 -2.815604   Corona  Brazil       NaN
4 -0.929755  Weather      UK       NaN
5 -0.929755  Weather      UK  0.000000
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this `.expanding` method. Thanks for sharing tho cool technique. Upvoted.

Comment: @x89 Hey, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: @quasi-human - exactly same I learnt this from another answer some years ago ;) So I always will remember it ;)

Comment: Could you also explain this method with expanding a bit?

Comment: @x89 - I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370666/what-are-pandas-expanding-window-functions) is good explanation